# How to detect Notification Center is pulled down/up in Android

Tags: android

Since onPause and onResume is not called when the notification overlay is pulled down in Android L, is there a way for my Activity to update accordingly after the Notification Center is pulled down and back up?

Edit: I'm trying to handle the cases where the user turns on/off internet from the Notification Center. The Activity should update accordingly based on whether or not the user has internet access.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize your Activity's **onWindowFocusChanged** callback to detect when notification is pulled down/up while your Activity is running:

```
@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) { 
      // notification is pulled up
    } else { 
      // notification is pulled down 
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm am afraid there is still no way to detect if the Notification Center is pulled pulled down.

You may want to reconsider if you need to implement a different behaviour when such an event occurs - maybe you'll find out it's not even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a receiver for the android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action. You'll be notified if the user changed the setting (but also for other types of network changes, so you'll need to handle these).

See [docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)