# How to pause an activity

Tags: android

When users wants to attend the phone in between the app as it is in process or running state . So, how we stop the running or processing state of an activity or app

Comment: Try to do it and post here a specific doubt. This question is too wide.

Answer (score 0):

An activity is automatically paused when an interrupt like a phone call occurs. The method onPause is called when it does. If you want to pause something in your app when, suppose your app is minimized, make the corresponding calls in the onPause method.

```
public void onPause(){
    //Your code
}
```

If you have a service or media running, you need to do as above. Android will handle all the internal processes that occur when an app is minimised.

**There is no 'pause button' for an app.**

For detecting notification bar's status, you can use:

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) { 
      // notification is pulled up
    } else { 
      // notification is pulled down 
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

For more refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031071/5040796

Comment: I know this method but when any notification comes then how the running app or activity will stop???

Comment: I have edited my answer for notification changes. Check the edit